# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when connecting via Cajo over SSL issue

Tags: java, ssl, rmi, cajo

I am working on a Cajo implementation and need to make it run over SSL.  For whatever reason a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException is thrown.  Can anyone please provide some help on how to get Cajo to work via SSL?  I am using Cajo v1.175.

I am certain this is a simple issue with a simple fix, but I am a noob when it comes to RMI...

Full code, certs and error messages are at http://www.mikebryant.com/misc/cajo/cajossl.zip

*Any* help is greatly appreciated!

As requested, here is some code examples and the error messages....
The server socket code I got from http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~akonstan/rmi-ssl/

### Server.java

```
private static int port = 61354;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    Remote.config(ip, Constants.PORT, null, 0);

    java.rmi.server.RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new cajotest.rmi.SecureRMISocketFactory());
    Cajo cajo = new Cajo();
    cajo.export(new ServiceImpl());

    System.out.println("Server running on " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + ":" + Constants.PORT);
}
```

### Client.java

```
private static String host = "192.168.56.1";


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Client using " + host + ":" + Constants.PORT);

    java.rmi.server.RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new cajotest.rmi.SecureRMISocketFactory());

    Cajo cajo = new Cajo();
    cajo.register(host, Constants.PORT);

    Object refs[] = cajo.lookup(Service.class);
    if (refs.length > 0) {
        Service svc = (Service) cajo.proxy(refs[0], Service.class);
        String helloResponse = svc.sayHello("Mike");
        System.out.println(helloResponse);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No server objects found");
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

### Server Output

keyStore is : E:/tmp/keys/server.keystore
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509

---

found key for : mykey
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 31434775225176154525188450095928359730439773654569875739006529498753775941836879335170711581345181627002505013136641662171665561909368111128992563200107296330496960757120954961536110026266883151124825419006377272595234135200675051213302816914418337984097764612958767550798419182794412912305446103091606209963556959114853256386233481900800240210577795238128981652820232312019642106408583884850663783871435028385309369039684834482184818872915700300803897953631336567205645337828655696590723579859939321644377438059078563879623268616615009655624038507147063801873971704632278047739002847454047756775144357906262202283709
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Apr 16 08:53:44 EDT 2014,
               To: Tue Jul 15 08:53:44 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  SerialNumber: [    4f991afd]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: FA 7D 37 D8 66 14 CC 5B   A6 BF EA 53 74 63 91 8F  ..7.f..[...Stc..
0010: EA 55 82 8F                                        .U..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 54 67 10 1F 22 79 9F C1   39 02 B3 99 31 4E 4F B7  Tg.."y..9...1NO.
0010: 86 5B 6C B6 35 95 97 77   A0 49 80 EC 53 A4 7E C1  .[l.5..w.I..S...
0020: 3F B0 0F 20 7B 80 D3 6B   32 C2 4B E4 E2 53 C0 59  ?.. ...k2.K..S.Y
0030: 53 98 C3 4D 93 5E F7 10   E5 51 19 DF A5 B8 27 90  S..M.^...Q....'.
0040: 58 AC 91 FA 5A 9A A0 73   CA C1 A0 08 A2 96 8E E2  X...Z..s........
0050: DE C6 0D 63 9A 66 52 BD   F4 22 3C 29 21 15 36 6F  ...c.fR.."<)!.6o
0060: 87 E5 EE 49 86 28 E4 67   30 11 BD CB B5 70 AD D0  ...I.(.g0....p..
0070: 22 AD 03 78 3D 9B 7D 65   DE 28 44 3E 4F BB 80 72  "..x=..e.(D>O..r
0080: 0E 3C 29 7D C2 18 4E DB   D5 F7 C3 A0 32 D9 E9 07  .<)...N.....2...
0090: 7D 84 A6 23 38 8E 63 F6   F2 A1 9B 1E AC DF BD 1A  ...#8.c.........
00A0: 9F 5A CA 9F 49 32 01 94   B3 F5 F6 64 6F 43 6D 35  .Z..I2.....doCm5
00B0: B5 71 E1 2E 6C FC C3 99   23 DE F9 EB A9 E8 FB 02  .q..l...#.......
00C0: 4F 7D 77 DE 9A F2 FF C2   2E F3 B3 A0 CF 5C 6F 23  O.w..........\o#
00D0: D1 B1 93 7B 55 BC C6 A6   2F 07 C2 0D E5 55 8D DD  ....U.../....U..
00E0: 54 74 2C 85 12 6C E6 7A   B0 63 6A 10 72 F9 39 38  Tt,..l.z.cj.r.98
00F0: 99 7C F4 C4 95 2E 79 48   C0 70 A9 B7 57 A9 55 46  ......yH.p..W.UF

]

---

trustStore is: E:\tmp\keys\server.keystore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Issuer:  CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4f991afd
  Valid from Wed Apr 16 08:53:44 EDT 2014 until Tue Jul 15 08:53:44 EDT 2014

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Issuer:  CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x34f4b1a1
  Valid from Wed Apr 16 08:54:40 EDT 2014 until Tue Jul 15 08:54:40 EDT 2014

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Server running on Coruscant/192.168.56.1:61354

### Client Output

Client using 192.168.56.1:61354
keyStore is : E:/tmp/keys/client.keystore
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509

---

found key for : mykey
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 17138097295393612277035352117769395039898411523084254468636172064694291643785627714254568170929877396708304047390061148924969763142078656182412595021000020409534532998798795520686728121819932399147428088113942915656945012724682101815391741129215424540207649843144893952660981710728604065430397993949203653373697078227603166902329372420465918295279504255056173129004094269357111536832825597754454857829397305965490792521265512567191812885625114031306416897590287126686684695535655220394890619907763314629130717883370421294661388162541292858875691164575058279131977342304495210869976587846586803189943875996789637083793
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Apr 16 08:54:40 EDT 2014,
               To: Tue Jul 15 08:54:40 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  SerialNumber: [    34f4b1a1]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 5E 19 97 98 E4 33 E9   9B B9 31 E9 B6 D0 F0 F2  v^....3...1.....
0010: 56 37 CE 18                                        V7..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 7D 63 DA B3 ED 5A 32 DB   48 66 80 89 5B 05 1C 36  .c...Z2.Hf..[..6
0010: 93 7D 47 75 D6 F1 74 82   7F 12 04 8C CB 20 AB E5  ..Gu..t...... ..
0020: 90 4A 5D B7 90 1E 98 5D   CF 7E 86 EA DC 3B 64 4A  .J]....].....;dJ
0030: 5D B3 DB 76 DE C0 65 1F   AB 07 22 08 D9 F3 F1 CF  ]..v..e...".....
0040: 4D 73 A8 E6 BC 94 44 02   39 0D 32 84 78 1E 32 DD  Ms....D.9.2.x.2.
0050: 42 4D 6C 53 B7 00 EE 3C   CE 3C 68 DA FA AA 28 A0  BMlS...<.

]

---

trustStore is: E:\tmp\keys\client.keystore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Issuer:  CN=Server, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4f991afd
  Valid from Wed Apr 16 08:53:44 EDT 2014 until Tue Jul 15 08:53:44 EDT 2014

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Issuer:  CN=Client, OU=Bar, O=Foo, L=Some, ST=Where, C=UN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x34f4b1a1
  Valid from Wed Apr 16 08:54:40 EDT 2014 until Tue Jul 15 08:54:40 EDT 2014

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1397762666 bytes = { 92, 155, 95, 199, 227, 200, 183, 73, 110, 151, 210, 240, 190, 70, 181, 238, 2, 129, 136, 117, 166, 211, 25, 2, 235, 239, 76, 228 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]

---

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:304)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at gnu.cajo.invoke.Remote.getItem(Unknown Source)
    at gnu.cajo.Cajo.register(Unknown Source)
    at cajotest.client.Client.main(Client.java:22)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:229)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    ... 14 more

Comment: Please include the relevant code and error in your post.

Comment: Added code and error messages. Thanks.

Comment: You should set the system property `javax.net.debug` on the client to `ssl,handshake,record` and analyze the debug output.

Comment: Marcel: the messages above are from the javax.net.debug..

Answer (score 0):

In the client, set the global socket factory after doing the lookup. Otherwise it applies to that too, and requires the Registry to be using SSL, which not clearly isn't.

You shouldn't use RMISocketFactory. It was deprecated in 1998, or at least obsoleted by RMIServerSocketFactory and RMIClientSocketFactory.